# How many $n×n$ binary matrices are there?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, matrices, proof-writing, induction

> How many $n×n$ binary matrices are there?

So, I have already proven that there are $2^n$ binary $n$-vectors, this way:

- There are $2^1$ binary $1$-vectors:
  $\begin{bmatrix}0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\end{bmatrix}$.

  So, then, I assume there are $2^k$ binary $k$-vectors, this way:

  $A(1) = 2^1 = 2$ | (there are $2^1$ $1$-vectors)

  $A(2) = 2^2 = 4 = 2A(1)$ | (there are $2^2$ $2$-vectors)

  $A(3) = 2^3 = 8 = 2A(2)$ | (there are $2^3$ $3$-vectors)

  $\vdots$

  $A(k) = 2^k = 2A(k-1)$ | (there are $2^k$ $k$-vectors)

  $A(k+1) = 2^{k+1} = 2·2^k = 2A(k)$ | (there are $2^{k+1}$ ${(k+1)}$-vectors)
- $(A(k))(2)= 2·2^k = 2(2A(k-1))$
- $2(2A(k-1)) = 2A(k)$

  $2(2A(k-1)) = 2·2·2^{k-1} = 2^2·2^{k-1} = 2^{k+1} = 2A(k) $

$\blacksquare$ QED

But I don't know how to use induction to prove this for two dimensions. 
The only thing that comes to my mind is that I have this $n$-vector:

$A=\begin{bmatrix} a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \ \end{bmatrix}$ which has $2^n$ possible combinations.

Now if I had a $n×n$ matrix

[image]

each line could be represented as an $n$-vector with $2^n$ possible combinations each, so since there are $n$ $n$-vectors, matrix $B$ would have $2^n·n$ possible combinations.

I don't know if this reasoning is correct, because it's more based on intution than anything, and if it's, I don't know if the explanation would count as a formal proof, so could you explain me how to prove **How many $n×n$ binary matrices are there?** please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: re-write the matrix all on one line. It now looks like a vector. How many elements are there in it?

Comment: "*each line could be represented as an $n$-vector with $2^n$ possible combinations each*"  Correct so far.  "... *so since there are $n$ $n$-vectors, matrix $B$ would have $2^n\cdot n$ possible combinations*"  Incorrect here.  Use your [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) properly.  You *multiply* the number of options for each together, not add.  We get then $\underbrace{2^n\cdot 2^n\cdots 2^n}_{n~\text{times}}$ which simplifies as people have below.

Answer (score 4):

We have $n^2$ entries , all of which can be $0$ or $1$. That makes $\large  2^{(n^2)}$ different binary matrices.

Answer (score 2):

You have $n^2$ entries and each of them can have two possible values. Therefore, there are $2^{n^2}$ such matrices.

Answer (score 2):

You have $n\times n$ terms and for each term you have two choices. Thus the answer is $$2^{n\times n} = 2^{n^2}$$ binary $n\times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks for your help. So it seems that the proof would be something like this (?); I have [image]

such that $B∈M_{n×n}$, so it has $n^2$ entries.

Now, if I put all those entries in a vector, I would have a $n^2$-vector, all whose entries could only be either $1$ or $0$; given the first theorem, that says that a binary $n$-vector has $2^n$ possible combinations, then a $n^2$-vector has $2^{(n^2)}$ possible combinations.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @egreg: This is a self-answer to "how many binary $n\times n$ matrices are there?" that incorporates the Comments posted by Readers under the Question.  So I think it does answer the Question.